# I want to display the sum of a column using php but it sending me 0

Tags: php, sql, database, mysqli

```
<?php
  $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","test");
  // Check connection
  if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

  $results = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT SUM(jumlah) AS jumlah_sum FROM finance_income"); 
  echo '<center>';

 while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($results)); 
 {
     echo "<p>" . "Rp " . number_format($rows['jumlah_sum']) . "</p>";
 }
 echo "</center>";

 mysqli_close($con);



?>
```

I already changes some code but when i open this php file it doesnt add all my number it just  print 0 in the web anybody know what happen?

```
Full texts  
id
timestamp
nama
cat_id
jumlah

1
2013-10-26 14:08:18
test
Iuran
400000

2
2013-10-26 22:06:35
test
Donasi
2000000

3
2013-10-27 10:51:32
test
Iuran
100000

4
2013-10-27 10:55:01
test
Iuran
100000

5
2013-10-27 11:01:38
test
Iuran
100000

6
2013-10-27 11:02:07
test
Iuran
100000
```

that are my database
Thanks You, Ryan

Comment: var_dump($results);  tell me the what is the result of it ?

Comment: you are mixing mysqli_* functions with mysql_* functions..

Comment: **Stick in your spokes** with that mix of MySQL. And don't make it all `MySQL_`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your are using `msqli_connect` for connection but using `mysql_query` for querying.
Do not  mix both libraries. use `mysqli_query` instead of `mysql_query`. Same for the `mysql_fetch_array`. use `mysqli_fetch_array`

```
 <?php
  $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","test");
  // Check connection
  if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

  $results = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT SUM(jumlah) AS jumlah_sum FROM finance_income"); 
  echo '<center>';

 while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($results)); 
 {
     echo "<p>" . "Rp " . number_format($rows['jumlah_sum']) . "</p>";
 }
 echo "</center>";

 mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: It doesnt work, it just print 0 on the page